# Integral inequality :$\int_0^1(f'(x))^2dx\geq 32\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx + 16\left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1f(x)dx\right)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, integral-inequality

Assume $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f'$ is integrable. Given $f\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=f\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)=f(1)-f(0)=0$, then prove that $$\int_0^1(f'(x))^2dx\geq 32\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx + 16\left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1f(x)dx\right)^2$$ My attempt: I tried to make the most out of the given information. Consider the integrals $$I_1=\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(x-\frac{1}{8}\right)f'(x)dx=\frac{f(0)}{8} - \int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}f(x)dx$$ $$I_2=\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(x-\frac{3}{8}\right)f'(x)dx=\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{8} - \int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx$$ $$I_3=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{4}}\left(x-\frac{5}{8}\right)f'(x)dx=\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{8} - \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{4}}f(x)dx$$ $$I_4=\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^{1}\left(x-\frac{7}{8}\right)f'(x)dx=\frac{f\left(1\right)}{8} - \int_{\frac{3}{4}}^{1}f(x)dx$$ Notice that $$I_1+I_2-I_3-I_4=-\left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1f(x)dx\right)$$ Hence $$\left|\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1f(x)dx\right|^2\leq \left(I_1+I_2-I_3-I_4\right)^2\leq 4\left(|I_1|^2+|I_2|^2+|I_3|^2+|I_4|^2\right)$$ Using C-S inequality, we get $$\left|I_k\right|^2\leq \frac{1}{2^8\times 3}\int_{\frac{k}{4}}^{\frac{k+1}{4}}(f'(x))^2dx ,\quad k\in \{0,1,2,3\}$$ Hence $$\left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1f(x)dx\right)^2\leq \frac{4}{2^8\times 3}\int_0^1(f'(x))^2dx$$ Upto this seems fine , but i am having trouble estimating the second term i.e $\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx$. I tried considering integrals like $\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}xf'(x)f(x)dx,\quad \int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)f'(x)f(x)dx$ etc, but they are not giving satisfactory results. Please see if i can improve this or is there some other approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for mentioning Wirtinger's inequality, i was not aware of it( have not studied fourier analysis yet). I will use two of its applications : $1)$ If $f(a)=f(b)=0$ then $$\frac{(b-a)^2}{\pi^2}\int_a^b(f'(x))^2dx\geq\int_0^a(f(x))^2dx$$ $2)$ If either one of $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ is zero then $$\frac{4(b-a)^2}{\pi^2}\int_a^b(f'(x))^2dx\geq\int_a^b(f(x))^2dx$$ Now using $(1)$ for the interval $\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right]$ we get $$\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{3}{4}}(f'(x))^2dx\geq\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{3}{4}}(f(x))^2dx$$ and using $(2)$ for intervals $\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]$ and $\left[\frac{3}{4},1\right]$ $$\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}}(f'(x))^2dx\geq\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}}(f(x))^2dx$$
$$\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^{1}(f'(x))^2dx\geq\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^{1}(f(x))^2dx$$ adding these three $$\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{0}^{1}(f'(x))^2dx\geq\int_{0}^{1}(f(x))^2dx$$ and i have already established that $$ \frac{4}{2^8\times 3}\int_0^1(f'(x))^2dx\geq\left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1f(x)dx\right)^2$$ Hence $$32\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx + 16\left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1f(x)dx\right)^2\leq\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{8}{\pi^2}\right)\int_0^1(f'(x))^2dx$$ and $\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{8}{\pi^2}\right)<1$

Answer (score 3):

My favourite technique for such kind of problems is to project them over $\ell^2$.

Let us see how that works in this case.

Let we define four ausiliary functions over $[0,1]$:
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} g_1(x) &=& f\left(\frac{x}{4}\right) \\
g_2(x) &=& f\left(\frac{x+1}{4}\right) \\
g_3(x) &=& f\left(\frac{3-x}{4}\right) \\
g_4(x) &=& f\left(\frac{4-x}{4}\right) \end{array}\right.\tag{1}$$
together with their Fourier series:
$$ g_k(x) = a_0^{(k)}+\sum_{n\geq 1} c_n^{(k)}\cos(2\pi n x)+\sum_{n\geq 1} s_n^{(k)}\sin(2\pi n x). \tag{2} $$
The initial constraints become $g_1(0)=g_4(0)$ and $g_2(0)=g_3(0)=0$; moreover:
$$ \int_{0}^{1/2}f(x)\,dx -\int_{1/2}^{1}f(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{4}a_0^{(k)}, \tag{3}$$
while by Parseval's identity:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2\,dx = \sum_{k=1}^{4}\left[\frac{{a_0^{(k)}}^2}{4}+\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left({c_n^{(k)}}^2+{s_n^{(k)}}^2\right)\right]\tag{4}$$
as well as:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f'(x)^2\,dx = \frac{\pi^2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{4}\sum_{n\geq 1}n^2\left({c_n^{(k)}}^2+{s_n^{(k)}}^2\right).\tag{5}$$
If now we translate the initial constraints as (the pointwise convergence of the Fourier series of $g_k$ is granted by $f'\in L^2$):
$$ a_0^{(k)}+\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n^{(k)}=0\qquad (k=2,3) $$
$$ a_0^{(1)}+\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n^{(1)}=a_0^{(4)}+\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n^{(4)}\tag{6}$$
and write down the continuity conditions $g_1(1)=g_2(0),g_2(1)=g_3(1),g_3(0)=g_4(1)$
the initial problem is finally projected over $\ell^2$ and we just need to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove the given integral inequality. As already remarked by Marco Cantarini, this is just a particular version of [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger's_inequality_for_functions) and the given constants are not optimal, but the outlined approach gives the chance to find both the optimal constants and the functions fulfilling the equality in the optimal inequality.